# Как прервать цикл if в Python и завершить программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, if, условия

Доброе день, помогите решить проблему есть программа калькулятор который считает ПДВ, вроде все работает, только **не правильно работает оператор if если при проверке я вожу число больше 3 х или любую другую букву.** Я хотел что бы программа прерывалась выводя сообщение о неправильном вводе. Вместо этого у меня сначала выводится еще один input потом заканчивается если ввожу число больше трех, если букву программа ломается.

````
from termcolor import colored

fun_dict = {1: 'C ПДВ', 2: 'Без ПДВ', 3: 'ПДВ'}

print(colored(on_color='on_red', text='\"""Налоговый калькулятор Украины 2021\"""'))
print(colored(color='red', text='Выберите пункт нажмите ENTER'))


def selection_calculation():
    """Функция выводит на экран выбор действия"""
    for key, value in fun_dict.items():
        print(key, '->', value)


def z_pdv():
    """Функция считает сумму заданную ПДВ и Без ПДВ""" 
    x = return_selection // 6
    y = return_selection - return_selection // 6
    print('Сумма с ПДВ ->', return_selection)
    print('Сумма ПДВ ->', x, 'грн')
    print('Сумма без ПДВ ->', y, 'грн')


def bez_pdv():
    """Функция считает сумму без С ПДВ и ПДВ"""
    x1 = return_selection * 20 // 100 + return_selection
    y1 = return_selection * 20 // 100
    print('Сумма без ПДВ ->', return_selection)
    print('Сумма с ПДВ ->', x1, 'грн')
    print('Сумма ПДВ ->', y1, 'грн')


def pdv():
    """Функция считает сумму с ПДВ и без ПДВ"""
    x2 = return_selection * 6
    y2 = return_selection * 6 - return_selection
    print('Сумма ПДВ ->', return_selection)
    print('Сумма с ПДВ ->', x2, 'грн')
    print('Сумма без ПДВ ->', y2, 'грн')


selection_calculation()

choice = int(input(colored(color='blue', attrs=['underline'], text='Выберите операцию :')))
return_selection = int(input(colored(color='blue', attrs=['underline'], text='Ведите сумму :')))

if choice == 1:
    z_pdv()
elif choice == 2:
    bez_pdv()
elif choice == 3:
    pdv()
elif choice > 3:
    print('Веденно неверное значение. Выберите значение от 1 до 3 включительно.')```
````

Comment: приведи код в работающий вид, сейчас он даже не запускается из-за colored

Comment: При заполнении поста неправильно выделил код , исправил

Comment: Немного позанудствую но if это не цикл, а условный оператор. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вместо этого у меня сначала выводится еще один input

Ничего удивительного. Оба инпута идут один за другим и только потом уже идет обработка первого.

Программа ломается при вводе буквы, потому что пытается привести введенные данные к целому числу. Нужно просто читать сообщения об ошибках.

Т.к. числа все равно не нужны, то приводить к числу не нужно

```
choice = input(colored(color='blue', attrs=['underline'], text='Выберите операцию :'))
```

и просто сравнивать со строкой:

```
if choice == "1":
    z_pdv()
elif choice == "2":
    bez_pdv()
elif choice == "3":
    pdv()
else:
    print('Веденно неверное значение. Выберите значение от 1 до 3 включительно.')
```

*Подозреваю, что следующим будет вопрос, как все это выполнять в цикле, но на эту тему здесь уже много ответов.*

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
choice = ''
while choice != ' ':
    choice = input('Выберите операцию ("пробел" для окончания)')

    if choice == '1':
        z_pdv()
    elif choice == '2':
        bez_pdv()
    elif choice == '3':
        pdv()
    else:
        print('Неверное значение. Выберите значение от 1 до 3 включительно.')
```

Тут `while choice != ' ':` - цикл до момента, пока пользователь не введет пробел (замените по вкусу на что-то свое) для прекращения

Comment: а 2й ввод куда ? return_selection

Answer (score 0):

Наворотил я кучу кода бессмысленного вроде все работает, только вот не могу побороть второй input что бы когда водится буква писало неверное значение все ломается((. Если убираю int функция не работает.

```
choice = (input(colored(color='blue', text='Выберите операцию :')))

while True:
    if choice == '1':
        return_selection = int(input(colored(color='blue', text='Ведите сумму :')))
        z_pdv()
        choice = (input(colored(color='blue', text='Выберите операцию :')))
    elif choice == '2':
        return_selection = int(input(colored(color='blue', text='Ведите сумму :')))
        bez_pdv()
        choice = (input(colored(color='blue', text='Выберите операцию :')))
    elif choice == '3':
        return_selection = int(input(colored(color='blue', text='Ведите сумму :')))
        pdv()
        choice = (input(colored(color='blue', text='Выберите операцию :')))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(colored(color='red', text='Выход из программы'))
        break
    else:
        print(colored(color='red', text='Веденно неверное значение. Выберите значение от 1 до 3 включительно.'))
        print(colored(color='red', text='Выход из программы'))
        break
```

Comment: уберите инт, после ввода сделайте проверку isdigit() если нет то нафиг если да то int и вызов функции

Comment: Спасибо все получилось.